# Why sometimes choose to use char instead of int to define a column in the case of pure numbers, no leading 0, not exceeding the value range of int?

Tags: mysql

As I said, I found a strange phenomenon when referring to other people's projects,

some people's table columns (qualified for the title) use char instead of tinyint, such as

```sql
create table A(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  a_seq char(9) comment 'The first one is 1, 2, 3 (national, private, foreign)'
  a_type char(1) comment '0 is normal, 1 is disable'
  a_status char(1) comment '0 is visible, 1 is not'
)
```

For `a_type` and `a_status`, both char(1) and tinyint(1) are one byte, and the comparison speed of numeric characters and numbers may be as fast, so the difference between the two is not very big.

So for `a_seq`, why not use int for storage? int only takes up 4 bytes, but char(9) takes up 9 bytes. If you add a `UNIQUE` index to `a_seq`, doesn't char(9) take up space and be slow?

---

To add, I also saw someone store the year (2020, 2021) in char(4) instead of shortint

---

Can anyone tell me the reason for this empirically, as I'm getting confused by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why sometimes choose to use char instead of int

A half of access libraries/frameworks provides parameter values as strings unconditionally. In this case the server compares the column and literal as strings, without any type convertion.

> the comparison speed of numeric characters and numbers may be as fast

I doubt. If one value to be compared is numeric and another one is string then both values to be compared are converted to floating point (double precision) values. See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).

> If you add a UNIQUE index to a_seq, doesn't char(9) take up space and be slow?

More disk space? of course. Slow? it depends.

Comment: Sorry for some ambiguity in my question, for
THE SECOND
My intention is that in the case of char(1) and tinyint(1), number-to-number comparisons may be as fast as character-to-character comparisons
And for
THE THIRD
I searched for the difference in query rate between int and char as the primary key, and in the case of equal footprint (such as char(4) vs int), the difference in query rate between them is very small
But when unequal, the smaller win)

Comment: When I designed a table once, there was a field that was the actual ID of the entity, denoted as `a_seq`, which is different from the auto-incrementing primary key `id`.
It is 19 digits long! But my partner ended up using char(19) and indexing it

The source of my doubts is it, why give up the bigint of 8 bytes and use the char of 19 bytes instead?

Comment: @Ice_Wift *It is 19 digits long!* BIGINT UNSIGNED may store this value. *why give up the bigint of 8 bytes and use the char of 19 bytes instead?* I cannot find any reason except library/framework specificity mentioned above. *number-to-number comparisons may be as fast as character-to-character comparisons* The difference in comparing time for numeric values and for short strings makes no sense in most cases. This time difference is too small while comparing with the time needded for another query execution steps.

Comment: @Ice_Wift In addition to what Akina said about it possibly being a constraint of the consumer framework outside the database, also sometimes some developers don't know any better and make poor design decisions by choosing improper data types. Or if the data is loaded from an external source or multiple external sources, some developers use string-based data types to simplify the Load process in their ELT workflow by not worrying about the actual type that could even change, from the external source that they have no control over.

Comment: @Akina - Wrong (or incomplete) on one point.  `WHERE int_col = "123"` converts the literal to int.

Comment: @RickJames In MySQL??? If you are correct then the Reference Manual contains incorrect information... Are you sure about what you said? can you prove it?

Comment: @Akina - The "proof" is indirect -- The Optimizer will consider using an index for `int_col=string`, but not for `char_col=number` The link you gave mentions "WHERE str_col=1" and "For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly."

Answer (score 0):

`INT` takes 4 bytes.  `CHAR(9)` takes at least 9 bytes.  If you are putting a number in `CHAR(9)`, then you can get up to 1 billion.  `INT` can handle a bigger number than that.

Significantly, putting numbers in `CHAR` (or `VARCHAR`) make them compare 'incorrectly' when using an inequality test:

```
 2  <  10    -- numeric comparison
"2" > "10"   -- because "2" > "1"
```

Which do you need?

There is a datatype called `YEAR`; wny not use that?

`VARCHAR` stores only the characters needed; `CHAR` pads to the length given.  Don't use `CHAR` unless you really need the padding.

There are similar arguments for using `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR`.

In general, use the appropriate datatype!

As for speed, ...  fetching the rows involved is far more costly than something as trivial as comparing one but with another.  The time difference is probably so insignificant as to be essentially impossible to measure.

The default collation in the MySQL 8.0 is a complex utf8mb4 (UTF-8) collation.  Even for a simple equality test, it must check each byte  in a complete way.  A simple example is "B" = "b" -- that is case folding.  Add accented letters or non-spacing accents and it becomes much more complex.